# Move the page number to the very bottom of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, page-numbering

I need to move the page number to the very bottom of the page, so it scrapes the bottom edge of the actual sheet (US letter).  How do we do that?

Comment: Beware of what you wish for: you may have to print it one day, on a printer which can't print on the last 5mm of the paper...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\usepackage[includefoot,bottom=0pt]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do more than move the page number. From comp.text.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\makeatletter 
\usepackage{xkeyval} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{picture,graphicx} 
\usepackage{atbegshi} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 


\pagestyle{fancyplain} 


\def\tempa{fmt=\fbox,x=.05,y=-.5,color=blue,scale=2.5,angle=90,% 
  cfoot=,rfoot=,lfoot=,chead=,rhead=,lhead=} 
\def\tempd{} 
\def\tempc#1=#2\@nil{% 
  \edef\tempd{% 
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempd}% 
    \ifx\tempd\@empty\else,\fi#1% 
  }% 
  \define@cmdkey[KV]{pagenr}[pgn@]{#1}[#2]{}% 
} 


\@for\tempb:=\tempa\do{\expandafter\tempc\tempb\@nil} 
\begingroup 
\edef\x{\endgroup 
  \noexpand\setkeys[KV]{pagenr}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tempd}}% 
} 
\x 
\newcommand*\FancyPageNos[1][]{% 
  \ifx\\#1\\\else\setkeys[KV]{pagenr}{#1}\fi 
  \cfoot{\pgn@cfoot}\rfoot{\pgn@rfoot}% 
  \lfoot{\pgn@lfoot}\chead{\pgn@chead}% 
  \rhead{\pgn@rhead}\lhead{\pgn@lhead}% 
  \AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{% 
    \textcolor{\pgn@color}{% 
      \put(\pgn@x\paperwidth,\pgn@y\paperheight)% 
      {\scalebox{\pgn@scale}{\rotatebox{\pgn@angle}% 
      {\makebox[0pt][c]{\pgn@fmt{Page \thepage}}}}% 
    }% 
}}}} 


\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhfoffset[R,L]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth} 
\def\headrule{{\color{blue}% 
  \hrule height1pt depth.5pt width\headwidth\relax 
  \vspace{2pt}\hrule height1pt depth.5pt width\headwidth 
  \vspace{-2pt}}%
} 

\def\footrule{{\color{red}% 
  \hrule height1pt depth.5pt width\headwidth\relax 
  \vspace{2pt}\hrule height1pt depth.5pt width\headwidth 
  \vspace{2pt}}% 
} 

\newcommand*\sstring[1]{{\tt\color{magenta}\detokenize{#1}}} 

\begin{document}

\FancyPageNos[fmt=\fbox,x=.05,y=-0.5,color=blue!45!red!75, 
  scale=5,angle=90,chead=\textcolor{cyan}{From \texttt{xwatermark} package}, 
  cfoot=Specimen fancy page numbers] 

\lipsum[1] 

\newpage 

\FancyPageNos[fmt=\texttt,x=.5,y=-0.15,color=purple,scale=2.5, 
  angle=0,chead=Sample use of \sstring\FancyPageNos] 

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The rubbishing of the syntax is not my fault. I simply copied my solution and pasted here. I hope you can arrange the code correctly.

Comment: Oops, the syntax is correct after all!

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanations what this does, for those of us who don't want to/can't read all that code.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: The macro \FancyPageNos provides a key-value interface for formatting and positioning the page number. The keys/options available are typified by the examples provided with the post. ‘fmt’ is the desired format, cfoot, rfoot, lfoot, chead, rhead, lhead have the same meaning as explained in the fancyhdr package documentation. Running the example provided gives further hints.

Comment: `x` and `y` give the coordinates of the page number in fractions of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight,` respectively. Note: the code comes from the development version of the _xwatermark_ pacakge.

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
\setlength{\footskip}{2cm}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Answers here should include some details and explanations. Actually answers so short are automatically flagged for moderator review.

Comment: This may be an approximate measure. However, since the location of the page number may depend on other components (text block height, for example), this would not solve the original question in general.